# Angular HttpHeaderS JWT

Tags: angular, http-headers, jwt

I am trying to implemnt JWT in my Angular Project. In my old Angular 2 Application was no problem. But with the new HttpHeaders it doesn't work now. I am sure that the token isn't null. I also tried it Bearer or Token or Basic.

Error Response:

> {"message":"JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided","code":"server_error","statusCode":403}

```
createProject(project: Project) {
    let header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    header.append('Authorization', environment.token);
    header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    return this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + "project/create", project, {headers: header, responseType: "text"});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your situation:

```
createProject(project: Project) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .append('Authorization', environment.token);

  return this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + 'project/create',
    JSON.stringify(project), {headers: headers, responseType: 'text'});
}
```

This is chaining all the `HttpHeaders` `set` and `append` calls together to get one set of headers. This works for a similar situation I have. Doing it the old way was giving me headaches too.

Also, you will need to make sure that `environment.token` is what the service expects. Usually something like `'Bearer <token...>'`.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but with working solution, reason behind this is **"HttpHeaders is immutable"** and thus behind the scenes they are cloned and should be stored in the object for further use

[image]

1) So, Something like this needs to be done :

```
headers = headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
```

2) Another point to note here is :

```
  header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Allowing access is done at the server end, not at the request end, and thus these headers are redundant.

3) If we want to use the existing headers and add/override some new headers i have done in following way :

```
 setRequestHeaders(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpHeaders {
    const headerSettings: { [name: string]: string | string[]; } = {};
    for (const key of req.headers.keys()) {
      headerSettings[key] = req.headers.getAll(key); // Read Existing headers
    }
    headerSettings[COMMON_CONSTANTS.HEADERS.AUTHORIZATION]
        : 'Bearer ' + this._cacheSvc.getFromSessionStorage(COMMON_CONSTANTS.ACCESS_TOKEN); // Add new Headers

   return new HttpHeaders(headerSettings); // final headers
}
```

Comment: @heyhoo does this answer your question, which has been dangling for quite sometime